# How to check a Float variable is empty or null IN JAVA

Tags: java, object, floating-point, is-empty, null-check

I have a Float variable which is initialised from a function returning the Float value, and there can be chance to return null in some cases. So I need to check the value in the variable is null or empty. If the value is empty I need to initialise variable wb1 with value 1. I am using Java Spring. This is the code currently I amusing,

```
Float wb1 = !StringUtils.isEmpty(getArea())?getArea() : 1.0f;
```

What is the correct way to check and initilize with value 1.0f

Comment: primitive float can not be null

Comment: `Float` is not a primitive type. `float` is a primitive type, but primitive types can't be empty or null. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: voting to close

Comment: And the way to test if a non-primitive is null is `wb1 == null`.  (This is basic Java 101 stuff.  I suggest you read a Java tutorial ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `Float` is an object and `float` is the primitive type.

null check is used for objects. For primitives you should use the default values check. For float the default value is 0.0f.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you mean Float, the box of `float`, you can use

```
Optional.ofNullable(wbCalculation(area.getArea(), CitySizeByArea.SIZE1.value, area.getRate1(), task.getTaskId())).orElse(0f)
```